# Detailed Parsing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, parsing

I wish to parse a dict for keyword `apples`, but the entry might not just be `apples`, but something like `I like apples`.

How can I parse a dict for this entry ?

Example dict:

```
[
    {
        'text': 'What fruit do you like ?',
        'start': 7.58,
        'duration': 6.13
    },
    {
        'text': 'I like apples',
# can be 'I hate apples', or 'No, not apples', or 'red apples are better than green', or any sentence that has the word apples
        'start': 14.08,
        'duration': 7.58
    },
    # ...
]
```

Code:

```
keyword = 'apples'
thisdict = function_that_returns_dict(some_id)

if thisdict["text"] = keyword:
    s = thisdict["start"]
    d = thisdict["duration"]
    print(s)
    print(d)
```

Expected Output:

```
14.08
7.58
```

Comment: Could you share the piece of code that you wrote to achieve the same ? We may be able to help you debug / improve that.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I can just parse the dict if the entry is exactly `apples`

Comment: @mukberty Post a sample input, and your expected output. What do you mean by _"something like"_? What other forms can it be in?

Comment: @mukberty Please post sample testcase and your code that you have written. We can help you improve the same and check using the sample testcase and expected output.

Comment: Done. @Selcuk .

Comment: For the simplest case you can use `if keyword in thisdict["text"]:` instead of `if thisdict["text"] = keyword:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search keywords in a dictionary like so:

```
test = {
    'apples' : 1,
    'oranges' : 2,
    'I like apples' : 3,
    'I like oranges' : 4,
    'I like apples and oranges' : 5}

for key in test.keys():
    if 'apples' in key:
        print(key+' : '+str(test.get(key)))
```

Output:

```
apples : 1
I like apples : 3
I like apples and oranges : 5
```

Your data structure appears to be a list of dictionaries; just iterate over the list elements.

```
test2 = [{
    'text': 'apples',
    'start': 1,
    'duration': 2},
    {'text': 'oranges',
    'start': 3,
    'duration': 4},
    {'text': 'I love apples',
    'start': 5,
    'duration': 6}]

for item in test2:
    if 'apples' in item.get('text'):
        print('text : '+item.get('text'))
        print('start : '+str(item.get('start')))
        print('duration : '+str(item.get('duration')))
```

Output:

```
text : apples
start : 1
duration : 2
text : I love apples
start : 5
duration : 6
```